Unable to use Python While Loop as I want
I am new to Python and trying to learn While loop.
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

a = max(list1)
idx = len(list1)-1

while a>4:
    a = list1[idx]
    print(a)
    idx = idx-1

As i am using 'while a>4', I was expecting the output to be only [7,6,5] but i get output as [7,6,5,4].
What am i not getting right?
Thank you

you only declare a=listed[idx] after you checked a>4.
So you have idx=3, then a=5 while it's compared to 5 and bc 5>4, the loop runs again and a=4 is set, which is printed

Can you explain what you are trying to do with this code.

a>4 will be checked once at the beginning of each iteration. Not when a variable changes

Have you considered usinga debugger to step through your code? That will help you to see what's going on.

A possible solution:
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# the initialization of a is not necessary
#a = max(list1)
idx = len(list1)-1

while True:
    a = list1[idx]
    if a>4:
        print(a)
    else:
        break
    idx = idx-1

My code is very similar to your from your code:

I have moved the exit condition (a>4) inside the loop; the loop condition has been substituted by True.
The break instruction causes the exit of the loop.
The execution of the print instruction is controlled by the if so no number greater than 4 will be printed.

The output of the execution is:
7
6
5

as you wish.

This happens because you first check variable 'a' and then update its value; so when you enter the loop 'a' equals 5 and then it gets updated. to fix this you can simply use the code below:

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

a = max(list1)
idx = len(list1) - 1

while (a := list1[idx]) > 4:
    print(a)
    idx = idx - 1

':=' puts list1[idx] value in 'a' inside the while and then we check the updated value immediately.

Your solution is excellent, but the operator := was introduced in Python 3.8 and we don't know the version of the interpreter of the OP. The initialization of a by the instruction a = max(list1) is not necessary in your code. However I have appreciated your code.

good point, i assume he does, otherwise he would suggest it. anyway in that case list1[idx] can be used in both condition and updating value of 'a' in while block.

I want to offer the beginner another way to solve the problem: with using elements of functional programming. As a rule, such solutions are more compact and clear:
from itertools import takewhile
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[print(a) for a in takewhile(lambda a: a > 4, reversed(list1))]

